Ubuntu Server connection drops seemingly at random
I'm running Ubuntu on a virtual server, and hosting a WebApp inside a container. I first noticed the issue when using SSH to access the server - every so often the connection would just freeze. I tested the internet connection from the server itself by pinging Google, and for some reason, this woke everything back up... SSH connection and container - all able to be accessed.
Is there some way I can write a keep-alive script that just pings a random website every so often?.. or can I solve the bigger problem here
Thanks in advance
EDIT:
I created a new virtual server using the exact same ISO, and have the exact same issue. There are other virtual servers on the machine that have been running for a long time with zero issues, so I'm doubtful it's hardware.
After experimenting/monitoring different scenarios, I can narrow the problem down to inactivity after 20 minutes; if the web page and API have been used within 20 minutes, everything remains functional, if left for 20 mins or more, everything falls over. Leads me to believe there is some rule in some config somewhere, maybe power management? Stumped.
EDIT 2:
It's not even inactivity :|
I manually refreshed my app every five minutes and it still broke after around 15 minutes. Tearing my hair out.

You could run ping -c 1 google.com > /dev/null as a cron job every minute, but I'm not sure that solves the underlying issue.

Strangely enough that doesn't actually work, I can confirm the cron process runs, but it doesn't wake up the connection.. Thanks @Jos

Is the host machine running the virtual server owned by you? maybe a hardware problem.

Yeah, it's owned by my company, with other virtual servers (windows) running with no issues...
